# Deploying angular build to S3 bucket

Tags: javascript, html, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

My question involves the index.html that is generated after `ng build --prod`. This is the one i get after running that command:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kudoshealth Dashboard</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="assets/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.f0d4a2f6b4b57a8b1a74.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime-es2015.5e3efc57355ca9fa37ac.js" type="module"></script><script src=""></script><script src="runtime-es5.5e3efc57355ca9fa37ac.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.c9393ad6cf868cd989cc.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.70587aa54d3cd9f0a3b6.js" type="module"></script><script src="scripts.c19d1667b1375f71590b.js" defer></script><script src="main-es2015.654b4a3d66cfb9c8fa63.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.654b4a3d66cfb9c8fa63.js" nomodule defer></script></body>
</html>
```

This angular project works fine on localhost, but once the dist output has been uploaded to the S3 bucket, there seems to be some issues such as this:

[S3 deployed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzA2y.jpg)

I ensure you that the login i am using is correct. All uploaded files are made public on the bucket too. The strange error is that there is no `8-es2015.8e909eab71372e40cabe.js` file in the dist. Im really sorry if the error is obvious or if I'm making a rookie mistake, but I've been stuck on this error for a few days and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: All we can figure out from this screenshot is that `companyId` is undefined (or more precisely there's a `something.companyId` where the `something` is undefined). Unfortunately, we have no idea what it is and where it's supposed to come from...

Comment: when the user logs in, the company id is retrieved using an Auth0 function. It works fine locally

Comment: I think you should update the href in   <base href="/">

Comment: what would this need to be updated to?

Comment: The first error suggests you are not hitting the right endpoint for authentication due to which companyId was not set, if it is working fine on local but giving error on other environment then it maybe that you have a variable storing base url of api and it is not getting updated according to the environment where build needs to be deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was a long persisting one in the background. The issues was resolved by changing my environment.prod.ts redirect url. It was set to an old one from a old branch on the repo that was redundant.